# Create Custom Ingress NGINX Template

Tags: kubernetes, cloud, devops

I created a custom ingress controller according to [this post](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/custom-template.md).
What I need to do is creating a proxy pass as https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/1615.

How can I do that?
Has anyone experienced with creating an advanced custom nginx ingress controller before?

I couldn't find a good article/tutorial about creating an advanced ingress configuration.

Thank you